# Looks now as if comments are reserved for what they shouldn't and shouldn't for what they should be used, or?

Tags: discussion, comments

Of course, like always a "free to make of it what ever" obervation...

If looking through the comments one would find long, long talks where mods are involved, or main feeders, while, if critic or pointing out errors are fast censured. Maybe a special BSE-rule.

But shure some might wish to express good observed attained opinions, or?

Answer (score 0):

**Not allowed**

I deleted several of your comments recently.

- These were comments under people's answers, which seemed to be criticism of the person answering the question -- and/or which weren't relevant to the OP's question.

  Criticising *people* contradicts the Code of Conduct which says,

  > Focus on the content, not the person.
- Similarly I also tend to delete comments which criticise BSE -- e.g. which criticise the existence of the site itself, and the fact that some people use it.

**Allowed**

- You also posted some short comments which seem intended as a partial answer to the OP's question.

  In theory those would be better posted as answers instead of as a comment -- but because they're on-topic (i.e. posted to answer the OP's question, and not critical of other users personally), I haven't been deleting those.
- I generally don't mind how long a comment is. I mostly only want it to be on-topic i.e. relevant to the OP's question, and non-hostile i.e. not criticising the *people* who are posting. And if you have a lot to say about a topic then post that as an answer instead of comments.

Comment: Look at the topic of what is uncensured left now: talks... An before? Critics for improvements. So again: what they are for? Everywhere, in all topics, critical points, no matter how right, are censured and Mods and means talks remain, crorrect if wrong. Maybe good to turn that proper, if wishing.

Comment: The purpose of the site is to answer the OP's question (and with a minimum of "blame" or controversy). Users can post a comment which tries to clarify an answer to the OP's question -- but not post a comment which attempts to criticise the person asking or answering.

Comment: That's Nyoms idea... peopl like right answers and they usually care less about people, so do SE. Wake upthat SE has another purpose as to gain the most from you... And the Chris-politic does neither fit to one or the other, but is actually after that what he says he likes to hinder...: entertaining and socializing. That what remains.